# Sort Tuples Row-Wise and Column-Wise

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, tuples

I've got a bunch of tuples that I want to insert into a 2D matrix according to the following rules:

1. A tuple can go to the right of of another tuple (in the same row) if the first element of the tuple is greater than or equal to the first element in the previous tuple.
2. A tuple can go under a tuple (in the same column) if the second element in the tuple is greater than or equal to the second element in the previous tuple.

This is an example of an acceptable solution:

```
(1,2) (2,1) (4,5)  
(8,6) (9,2) (9,8)
```

In other words, column-wise the tuples are sorted by the second element in the tuple and the row-wise by the first element. I realise that these rules can't always be 100% satisfied but I need to think of an algorithm that minimises the number of violations of the rules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a requirement on number of rows and columns? otherwise you could put them all in one row

Comment: No there's definitely more than 1 row/ column. Like at least 5 in each dimension.

Answer (score 1):

We can definitely avoid either row **or** column violations completely, but simultaneously avoiding both **depends on courtesy of data and not algorithm**.

Here is what I came up with.

Let us assume a 2-d array of dimensions nX2n.

**Step 1**:Sort all the tuples based on first element,lets call it TUP_1.

**Step 2**:Sort all the tuples based on second element,lets call it TUP_2.

**Step 3**:

```
i=0
while(i<n)
{
 Pick first n tuples(unmarked) from TUP_2 which are at Positions a,b,c......
 in TUP_1 such that a < b < c and so on.

 Mark the picked tuples.     

 fill the ith row with:
 first element from tuples in even positions.
 second element from tuples in odd positions.
 increment i.
}
```

**Note**:The above algorithm due to the condition

```
 a < b < c would always avoid any violation in row.
```

However, it would completely avoid the column violation if

```
 the elements from TUP_2 are always picked in order without any skipping.
```

If they are not, then there are chances that column violations can occur.

**Example**:Let us assume 3X4 matrix

Let the input contain following tuples.

```
(12,6) (12,1) (2,1) (11,1) (8,6) and (4,5).
```

Sorting, the tuples based on first element will give TUP_1

```
(2,1) (4,5) (8,6) (11,1) (12,1) and (12,6).
```

Sorting the tuples based on second element will give TUP_2

```
(2,1) (11,1) (12,1) (4,5) (8,6) (12,6).
```

Now performing step 3

```
(2,1) and (11,1) get picked up from TUP_2 because the tuples are at position
1 and 4 in TUP_1 and 1 < 4 and first row is filled as.

(2,1),(11,1)

(12,1) and (12,6) get picked up from TUP_2 because the tuples are at position
5 and 6 in TUP_1 and 5 < 6 and second row is filled as.

(12,1),(12,6)

(4,5) and (8,6) get picked up from TUP_2 because the tuples are at position
2 and 3 in TUP_1 and 2 < 3 and third row is filled as.

(4,5),(8,6)
```

Hence, the 3X4 matrix is:

```
(2,1),(11,1)
(12,1),(12,6)
(4,5),(8,6)
```

Comment: Sorry should've clarified- tuples must stay the same before and after sorting I.e. Elements can't be mixed.

Comment: @user3396592 When I say sort the tuples based on first element, it means that there is no comparison between any two tuples second element.

Comment: @user3396592 When I say sort the tuples based on second element, it means that there is no comparison between any two tuples first element.

Comment: @user3396592 I never meant mix the elements. Please suggest me where I am mixing the elements.

Comment: @user3396592 The tuples remain same with respect to first and second element of a tuple.

Comment: @user3396592 Kindly suggest why my solution is not in terms with your question.

Comment: fill the ith row with:
 first element from tuples in even positions.  Doesn't this imply that you take elements out of tuples? Could you possibly show an example of your algorithm running on say 9 tuples in a 3x3 grid?

Comment: @user3396592 I can't show u on 3x3 because 3  is odd.As only tuples can sit, and every tuple has two elements, number of columns must be even.

Comment: OK...can you explain through a 3x4 example?

Comment: @user3396592 Updated my answer.